# ng-bootstrap modal not working

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Modal is not opening properly.
below is the screen shot:[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySooO.png)

this is my package.json
"dependencies": {
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"": "^5.2.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
"angular4-slimscroll": "^1.0.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},

have found below things which is causing the issue:
for my app when modal is opened there is no classes related to modal in the dom element. check below pic:
[my example dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivppw.png)

while is demo in ng-bootstrap hosted example, dom element is as below:

[dopm from ng-bootstrap modal demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFAXa.png)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me by applying this css class in style.scss file

```
.modal-open .modal
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```